# Как преобразовать URI одного типа к другому?

Tags: java

На вход поступает URI вида

```
content://media/external/images/media/2
```

Как из него получить такой средствами Java?

```
file:///mnt/sdcard/Android/data/.../cache/photo.jpg
```

Comment: Это один и тотже файл?

Answer (score 1):

Все дело в том, что URI вида `content://media` - это фактически запись в БД со ссылкой на сам файл. Ссылка на файл при этом находится в колонке `MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA`. Собственно что и остается извлечь:

```
public String getPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) 
{
  Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, null, null, null, null);
  cursor.moveToFirst();
  return cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
}
```

Comment: Разве это ссылка? По-моему это просто реализованное поведение контентпровайдера на Uri на метод query(...)

Comment: This is SPA... eeee REST!!!

Comment: @rasnisha контентпровайдер это по факту и есть хранение данных или ссылок на данные (как в данном случае) в БД. Так что здесь это ссылка